# Does neo4j java driver rollback transactions automatically when an error occurs?

Tags: java, neo4j, transactions, neo4j-driver

I am running the below code to check if rollback call occurs. However, I am getting this error:

```
Could not rollback transaction  org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Can't rollback, transaction has been rolled back
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.util.Futures.blockingGet(Futures.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalTransaction.rollback(InternalTransaction.java:46)
```

Is it not possible to manually rollback the transaction?

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver(neo4jUrl, AuthTokens.basic(neo4jUsername,neo4jPassword));
Session session = driver.session();

Transaction tx = null;
try{
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    String insertQuery = "CREATE(n:Person{id:8,name:'Person6',age:26}) ";
    tx.run(insertQuery);

    String delQuery = "MATCH(n:Person{id:3}) DELETE n";
   // String delQuery = "MATCH(n:Person{id:2}) DELETE n";
    tx.run(delQuery);

    tx.commit();
    System.out.println("Trnx committed");
}catch(Exception e){
    tx.rollback();
    System.out.println("Transaction rolled back.");
} finally {
    if (session != null) session.close();
    if (driver != null) driver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with `tx.isOpen()`.
A simpler solution however is to just close the transaction, if it's not committed, it's going to be rolled back.

```java
try (Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction()) {
    // try-with-resources automatically closes the transaction
    // [...]
}
```

Side note: you don't want to create a driver every time you run a transaction.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.The code that i have provided above does not create a new driver every time I run a transaction .Am i wrong?You have mentioned that it is not necessary in your side note .So should make any change to it,or is the driver creation code correct?

Comment: If the driver creation is in the same method as the transaction creation, then it is likely incorrect. If that's not the case and you grouped both in the same snippet for readability, then it is fine. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense.Thanks for the clarification.In my actual program logic i have created the driver in the class constructor.The above code snippet was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

A transaction is automatically rolled back if it fails.

The (very confusing) error message "Can't rollback, transaction has been rolled back" is trying to tell you that your attempt to roll back failed because the transaction was already rolled back.

Also, as suggested by @fbiville, the [documented](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org.neo4j.driver/org/neo4j/driver/Transaction.html) suggestion is to wrap the transaction in:

> a try-with-resources block, which ensures in case of any error in
> try block, the transaction is automatically rolled back on close.
> Note that ROLLBACK is the default action unless commit() is called before closing.

Comment: Can i know in which case will this rollback function come in use? Since the transaction is rolled back as the default action,there is no point to manually call this function...is there?

Comment: It is better to be safe and follow the recommended coding pattern, as that should cover all corner cases.

Comment: I understand that this is the best approach ...But i wanted to know if there was any case that you had come across or used the rollback method call manually.

Comment: No, I always used the documented approach, and never needed to explicitly roll back.